# How to define a interface datatype?

Tags: apex, data-types, interface

I was preparing for PD1 exam and came across the below sentence on interface in the developer documentation which I’m unable to understand. Can anyone help with an example as to what the below statement implies?

> If you define a variable whose type is an interface, any object
> you assign to it must be an instance of a class that implements the
> interface, or a sub-interface data type.

Comment: This "in any place you can use another data type name" is wrong. The following sentence is a bit more helpful. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm and Google as it is a common feature in other languages e.g. Java.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @KeithC Yes, you can use an interface in any place you can use another data type name. That's a perfectly accurate description, unless you have a counterexample?

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate, citing three questions we have here on SFSE that provide examples of interfaces and how to use them. If you're still confused after reading through those, feel free to let us know, we can reopen your question for you once you [edit] in any additional questions you may have.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, can you please give an example to understand the below statement. I am super confused. If you define a variable whose type is an interface, any object you assign to it must be an instance of a class that implements the interface, or a sub-interface data type.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Reading it again, I take your point. Just not getting to the more detailed point of substituting the interface for the concrete types that extend it.

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng I actually understand how interfaces work. What I was not able to understand is the point in dev guide where they mentioned that you can use interface as a datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117920/abstract-interface-classes-oh-my-question-on-approach), [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123048/why-use-an-interface-in-apex), and [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28510/what-is-interface-method-in-salesforce), here's some additional information.

Interfaces are used to guarantee that a given method exist on an object. This allows generic algorithms to use data types that may not exist yet. This is explored extensively in the questions above.

As a final example, consider the following code:

```
interface i1 {
  void method1();
}
interface i2 extends i1 {
  void method2();
}
class c {
  void method1() { }
  void method2() { }
}
class c1 implements i1 {
  void method1() { }
  void method2() { }
}
class c2 implements i2 {
  void method1();
  void method2();
}
```

Given all this, the following is allowed:

```
i1 value1 = new c1();
i1 value2 = new c2(); // Allowed, i2 implements i1
i2 value3 = new c2();
```

While the following is not:

```
i1 value1 = new c(); // does not implement i1
i2 value2 = new c1(); // does not implement i2
```

As you can see, the variable's data type determines which objects it can hold. The difference here is that c1 and c2 are *unrelated* to each other. They share some common methods as defined by the interface, but they can do completely separate things.

For other examples, please read the answers linked at the top of this answer. They go in to a lot of detail and examples. This answer is meant to supplement those answers with details about interface inheritance.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for the clear answer. Now I’m able to understand it.